# How to disabled a list item?

Tags: javascript, listitem, disabled-control

I am building a currency converter right now, and Im bumping into a question that shows me cannot read property 'classList' of null. I follow the youtube Video step by step. I wonder what causes this problem. Can anyone help please? What am I do here is basically add the "disabled" class to the list item which is clicked.

```
function newCurrenciesListItem(currency) {
if (currenciesList.childElementCount === 0) {
    baseCurrency = currency.abbreviation;
    baseCurrencyAmount = 0;
}
addCurrencyList.querySelector(`[data-currency=${currency.abbreviation}]`)**.classList.add("disabled");**
const baseCurrencyRate = currencies.find(c => c.abbreviation === baseCurrency).rate;
const exchangeRate = currency.abbreviation === baseCurrency ? 1 : (currency.rate / baseCurrencyRate).toFixed(4);
const inputValue = baseCurrencyAmount ? (baseCurrencyAmount*exchangeRate).toFixed(4) : "";

currenciesList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
    `<li class="currency ${currency.abbreviation === baseCurrency ? "base-currency" : ""}" id=${currency.abbreviation}>
<img src=${currency.flagURL}  class="flag">
<div class="info">
    <p class="input"><span class="currency-symbol">${currency.symbol}</span><input type="text" placeholder="0.0000" value=${inputValue}></p>
    <p class="currency-name"${currency.abbreviation} - ${currency.name}</p>
    <p class="currency-rate">${exchangeRate} ${baseCurrency} = 1 ${currency.abbreviation}</p>
</div>
<span class="close">&times;</span>
```

`)
}

Comment: In which line do you get the `null` error? How are you getting the value?

Comment: can you put your code on stackblitz.com so we can reproduce the error ?

Comment: adding class "disabled" doesn't disable anything - you want to add disabled **attribute** to actually disable

Answer (score -1):

```js
addCurrencyList.querySelector(`[datacurrency=${currency.abbreviation}]`).classList.add("disabled");
```

Here you are selecting an element using attribute selector, but it returns null because no match is found(or most likely the element doesn't exist). Check if the element you're looking for is a child of `addCurrencyList` and that it has the attribute `data-currency` with the same value as in the parameter(`currency.abbreviation`).

Read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) to learn more about how CSS attribute selectors work.

quote:

> A NodeList object, representing the first element that matches the
> specified CSS selector(s). If no matches are found, null is returned.
> Throws a SYNTAX_ERR exception if the specified selector(s) is invalid.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

Comment: "but it returns null because the element doesn't exist" - how do you know? OP hasn't posted ANY html